# Show Caller id on calls from Mobile

Tags: twilio, caller-id

How do I get my twilio Virtual landline number to show as caller id when I call my customer from my cellphone? Both my cell phone and twilio virtual landline numbers are "verified" with twilio.

Comment: Please don't spam tags that are not relevant or only tangentially relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To make your Twilio number appear, you would need to generate the outbound call to the customer from Twilio. There are a couple of ways you can do this. The easiest is likely [triggering a call to your phone first with the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls) then connecting you to the customer using [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) and setting the [`callerId` to your Twilio number](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#callerid). If you wanted to do the entire thing starting from an outbound call on your phone, you could build an app that let you dial a Twilio number, then use [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather) to take the number you want to dial, and then connect the call out to that number. And the hardest way is building yourself an application using the [Twilio Voice SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks) so you can open the app and dial your customer.

Comment: I like the sound of the middle option, thank you. I'll look it into further...